# Surface Tension: The line integral, the surface integral... and something in between?

Tags: vectors, path-integral, surface-tension

**Surface Tension as a Line Integral**

I have seen the surface tension force defined by multiple [source](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.cns.gatech.edu/%7Epredrag/courses/PHYS-4421-13/Lautrup/surface.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiZzNLv8_frAhWSknIEHU7cB5EQFjAAegQICRAC&usg=AOvVaw3VKMF51OwySqyRYwJ6yzE6)s as the following line integral over the contact curve C (with trivial differences in notation among sources for the differential length element and surface tension coefficient, which I shall call $dl$ and $\gamma$):

**Eqn. 5.3:** $ \quad \quad \quad \vec{F_{ST}} \equiv \int_C \gamma \hat{T} \times \hat{n} dl$

where $\hat{T}$ and $\hat{n}$ are the unit vectors tangent to the contact curve and normal to the interfacial surface, respectively.

$\\$

**Surface Tension as a Surface Integral**

[Here](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/336L/Fluidhtml/node41.html) it is demonstrated that the surface tension line integral can be written as a surface integral over the interfacial surface $S$ (via Stokes' theorem):

**Eqn. 3.10:** $ \quad \quad \quad \vec{F_{ST}} = - \iint_S \gamma (\nabla \cdot \hat{n}) \hat{n} dS$

where $\nabla \cdot \hat{n}$ represents the mean curvature of the surface.

$\\$

**Surface Tension as a Line Integral with the Integrand of the Surface Integral?**

I believe I understand the previous formulae. However, [this source](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://web.mit.edu/2.21/www/Lec-notes/Surfacetension/Lecture3.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjD0b-x_ffrAhUGlHIEHafdDK8QFjABegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw0k0C9TqVqxJ44wiAg4DLdR) writes an integral that seems to me inconsistent with Eqns 5.3 and 3.10:

**Eqn. 27:** $ \quad \quad \quad F_{ST}^z = \vec{z} \cdot \int_C \gamma (\nabla \cdot \hat{n}) \hat{n} dl$

where $F_{ST}^z$ is the vertical component of the surface tension force (which the article calls the curvature force), and I would assume $\vec{z}$ is the vertical *unit* vector but I do not see it explicitly stated. Since $F^z=\hat{z} \cdot \vec{F}$ (by the nature of vector components), I would expect Eqn. 27 implies (let's assume constant $\gamma$ for convenience)

**Eqn. 27':** $ \quad \quad \quad \vec{F_{ST}} = \gamma \int_C \;  (\nabla \cdot \hat{n}) \hat{n} \; dl$

I am at a loss how this can be consistent with the integrals in Eqns. 5.3 and 3.10, much less derived from them (reproduced below for easy visual inspection).

**Integral 5.3:** $ \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \gamma\int_C \;  \hat{T} \times \hat{n} \; dl$

**Integral 3.10:** $ \quad \quad \quad \quad -\gamma \iint_S  \; (\nabla \cdot \hat{n}) \hat{n} \; dS$

$\\$

**Some Possible Resolutions**

$\vec{z}$ may not be a unit vector, and there is some relation in the style of $dS=dldz$. This seems implausible because on the same line as Eqn. 27, that source carries out the dot product with $\vec{z}$, where its norm appears to be 1.

I may have mistakenly imagined notations to be equivalent when they are not. All mentions of what I have called $\gamma$ in the three sources (called $\alpha$, $\gamma$, and $\sigma$ in the order I presented the sources) seem to be consistent and indeed the standard surface tension coefficient, as implied by their use in other relations in those texts (such as the Young-Laplace Equation). I am similarly confident in my translation of the line element "$dl$" ($dl$, $dr$, and $dl$ in the sources respectively).

The manifolds of integration (the curves and surfaces) may not actually be the same in the different sources. I fail to see how integrating over one curve or another could resolve what seems to me to be roughly an issue of dimensionality.

The "curvature force" expressed in Eqn. 27 is not the same as the "surface tension force" referred to by the other sources, and I should not have labeled the expression in Eqn. 27 as "$F_{ST}^z$" and instead retained the source's label "$F_c$" If this is the case, how are the curvature force and surface tension force related?

$\\$

**tl;dr Explicit Question**

How does the integral expression in Eqn. 2.7' relate to the line integral in Eqn. 5.3 and the surface integral in Eqn. 3.10?

Comment: There can never be fruitful discussion about the mathematical nature of surface tension without going into the language of tensors

Comment: @Buraian is it possible to derive "Eqn 27" using tensors?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_stress

Comment: @Buraian Thank you for the link, but unfortunately I did not see anything in it that would help answer the question. Perhaps you are thinking that the relationship between surface stress and surface tension can be used to derive the integral expressions for the surface tension force, but I do not see how one would do that.